# How to extract last 5 digits from a link

Tags: c#, asp.net

how do i extract the last 5 digits in C# of a link, for example

```
www.mywebsite.com?agent_id=12345
```

now I want to save the 12345 in a session variable

```
Session["agent_id"] = ???
```

Comment: use string.Substring(string.length - 5, string.length)

Comment: why are you doing this the hard way instead of reading the `Request.QueryString`?

Comment: To Andrew's point, what if the url is `www.mywebsite.com?agent_id=12345&hello=adf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get the agent_id value from the current request, then Marcos' answer will get you what you want.

However, if the "link" you are referring to is in some other string variable, your best bet is to use regular expressions.

```
string someUrl = "www.mywebsite.com?agent_id=12345";
var match = Regex.Match(someUrl, "[?&]agent_id=(\d+)";

if (match.Success) {
    Session["agent_id"] = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I  think `var id = Request["agent_id"]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query string property for that

```
string agentId = Request.QueryString["agent_id"];
```

more info for QueryString [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)